# Where exactly eigen vectors and eigen values are useful in neural network?

Tags: linear-algebra, neural-networks

The question is a little vague but if someone throws some simple use case and explain the problems it helps to solve in the context of neural networks, simpler is better. source would be helpful.

cool thanks!

Comment: The question proposes that they are useful. Why do you think so?

Comment: I'm going through some lectures on linear algebra(specifically focused on neural networks). where lecturer mentioned eigenvalues and eigenvectors are useful but he didn't explain where.

Comment: One example is the use of SVD (singular value decomposition) for Dimensionality Reduction. There's also this medium article [Machine Learning & Linear Algebra — Eigenvalue and eigenvector](https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/machine-learning-linear-algebra-eigenvalue-and-eigenvector-f8d0493564c9).